# Binomial Theorem / Taylor Series Help

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, binomial-theorem

How do I use Binomial Theorem on the function $\ln(-3x + 1)$?

The question requires me to compute a Taylor series for this function and I'm **required** to use the Binomial Theorem.

I understand how the theorem works and how to compute normal functions with exponents with the Binomial Theorem. However, this function is a little bit different in that it includes an "ln" operation.

Since the base formula for the Binomial Theorem is $(1 + x)^k$, how would I manipulate the "ln" operation so that it becomes an exponent "k"?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Why do you want to use only Binomial theorem to compute the TS? You may expand $(1-3x)^{-1}$, then integrate both sides... Assuming ($|3x| \lt 1$)

Comment: Perhaps you mean the binomial *formula*?  You can expand $(1-3x)^{-1}$ by the binomial formula.